# QField Value Relation

Tags: qgis, qfield

I wish to use a Value Relation to select species from a list. However the list may not be exhaustive, so I want to be able to add to the list in the field. I could of course use another free text field to capture values not in the list, but ideally would like to be able to update the list - a non-spatial layer (table) called 'species'.

How can I open a form for 'species' QField so I can add a value in the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your table of values ('species') as a geopackage into QGIS. For the mapping layer - in the Value Map (or Value Relation) widget, there's an option to "Load Data from Layer".
If that species table is editable in QField, you can add values to it in the app.